# Docker context not available on the CLI

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image locally for development purposes and it seems I have been wasting my time today. I am seriously considering downgrading to an older version because `docker build -t tagname`  used to work, but now it seems I have to use `docker build -t tagname - < Dockerfile` and it is throwing random errors that I finally tracked down to docker not being able to find thins!

I found on the Dockersite that [building "from the stdin" has no context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy:%7E:text=If%20you%20build%20using%20STDIN%20(docker%20build%20%2D%20%3C%20somefile)%2C%20there%20is%20no%20build%20context%2C%20so%20COPY%20can%E2%80%99t%20be%20used.), so you cannot use the COPY command! But they give not work arounds. How do I set the context so I can use COPY? How do I build locally other than on the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

DOH!

I found the answer in my notes finally:

`docker build -t tagname .`

That one little `.` was missing from my initial attempts and that made all the difference. Thanks @DOCKER for not documenting that option.

Comment: It's all documented

Comment: Not easily findable by Google. Or I would not have posted here...